# How to filter ProfileList with wildcards

Tags: powershell, regedit, registrykey

I'm writing a script to help streamline the deletion of users profile list's on our Citrix servers. I cant figure out how to filter the ProfileImagePath by wildcards.

On our Windows 2008 servers in Regedit I can search and sort the profile list of users cia its Profileimagepath but this gets all the users, I cant seem to extend that filter to only bring back wildcard entries.

```
set-location | 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows 
NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' |% {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath } | Select 
profileImagePath=username*
```

What I am getting is the whole list of user profiles, or if I put the filter =username* entry I get an error, What I wanted to get was just the results of the wildcard, Ideally just the usernames I put in the wildcard are what I want returned.

Comment: as AnsgarWiechers pointed out, your code is _broken so badly that i can't imagine how you got any output at all. [*grin*] ///// here's an alternate method for getting the local user profile paths that is somewhat easier than using the registry ... `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile).LocalPath -like '*[1st2LetersOfMyUserName]*'` --- that gives my user profile path.

Comment: Hey @Lee_Dailey Yea, I actually done the code in multiple steps, so I first set the location then ran that, then ran get-childlocation and now I cant get my code to work where it showed the folders via profile name.

Comment: you will need to post the full code _as you ran it_ to get help with that code. the stuff you have posted is NOT going to work. [*grin*] ///// have you tried the `Get-CimInstance` stuff? it returns an object that is much more "standard powershell"-ish - and usually easier to work with. plus, it has a `.Delete()` method ...

Comment: No I haven't tried that, however Ansgar's script worked, gave me exactly what I wished for, I will have to look into how to pipe a delete onto the end of it so it just removed that one user.

My PS doesnt even pull a `get-help` for `Get-CimInstance` on this server so I dont know if I can get that working as it wont run the update.

Comment: ah! your server may be running psv2 if it is not able to be updated for some reason. in that case, you should be able to use `Get-WmiObject` instead of the new `CIM-*` cmdlets. in any case, you have it wokring and that is what counts! [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey 

Plan to continue on the MVA before I do anymore powershell... or damage depends on which way you look at it. But I do know the first part of this script is done, In time I will work out how to delete the Registry key once we find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is utterly broken. Please go find a PowerShell tutorial before proceeding any further.

- `Set-Location` does not produce output, and even if it did, piping cmdlet output into a string wouldn't do anything at all.
- You must not wrap statements at arbitrary places like you do in your sample code.

  - The wrapped registry path string will preserve the embedded newline (thus not matching what you want it to match).
  - Putting the argument of the `Select-Object` statement on the next line without escaping the newline will run `Select-Object` without arguments and the arguments as a separate statement (which most likely will throw an error because the arguments aren't a valid statement by themselves).
- `=` is an *assignment* operator in PowerShell. *Comparison* operators are `-eq` (equality), `-like` (wildcard matches), and `-match` (regular expression matches).
- You need `Where-Object` for filtering pipelined objects, not `Select-Object`. The latter is for selecting object *properties*.

You propbably meant to do something like this:

```
$username    = '...'
$profilePath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList'

Get-ChildItem $profilePath | Where-Object {
    (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath).ProfileImagePath -like "*${username}*"
}
```

or (simpler) like this:

```
$username    = '...'
$profilePath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList'

Get-ChildItem $profilePath |
    Get-ItemProperty |
    Where-Object { $_.ProfileImagePath -like "*${username}*" }
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I am going through MVA in powershell for beginners, and know I have bitten of quite a bit by trying to do this task, so I do appreciate you still taking to time to write back a response.